# How to remove a specific word from the beginning of the string?

Tags: php, regex

Here are some examples:

```
meaning hello
meaning
hello meaning
whatever
```

I want to remove word `meaning` if it is in the beginning of the sentence. So here is the expected result for each of those expressions:

```
hello
meaning
hello meaning
whatever
```

**Note1:** If the whole expression (regardless surrounded spaces), then I want to keep it.

**Note2:** Those expressions above are all separated. So assume them as different entries.

---

Here is what I've tried: `^\s*meaning\s+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EjuqM/1/)) - its problem is it even removes `meaning`.

Comment: `if it is in the beginning of the sentence` ... can you show us the actual full text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's for a dictionary search engine .. Some people want to search for `hello` and they write `meaning hello` as entry .. So, I want to remove `meaning` if it was as a prefix of the entry. So, in `meaning hello` the expected result is `hello`. (But in `hello meaning` or `meaning` nothing should remove)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `\s+` is matching the newline characters at the end of the line that contains only `meaning`. Change that to `[ \t]+` instead:

```
^\s*meaning[ \t]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EjuqM/2/)

Comment: Or simply `^\s*meaning +`

Comment: You probably want a word boundary after `meaning\b` to avoid matching `meanings`, `meaningful`, etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Like this? `^\s*\bmeaning\b +`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not required because the regex asserts a space or tab after meaning

Comment: @stack the `\b` are not required as the regex asserts beginning of line (`^`) at the start and then a space or tab at the end.

Comment: @stack if you know you won't have tab characters then `^\s*meaning +` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove `meaning` when occurring at the start of the input, possible prefaced by whitespace, when no other terms follow, then you could use a positive lookahead:

```
^\s*meaning\b(?= .*\S)
```

This asserts that only `meaning` is matched, and it is also followed by any other non whitespace text on the same line.

### Demo

Comment: @stack Sorry, I had a typo in my pattern, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting a 4 minute solution that came in mind faster than any other :)

```
$data_0 = 'hello meaning';
$data_1 = 'meaning hello';

$dToArray = explode(' ', $data_0);
$string = '';
$counter = count($dToArray);

for($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

    if (strtolower($dToArray[$i]) === 'meaning' && $i === 0){
        continue;
    }
    $string .= $dToArray[$i] . ' ';
}
echo $string;
```

I hope this triggers an idea for you.

Comment: thx .. upvoted .. however I wanted just a regex for doing this

Comment: Yes, regex, why would you write 10 lines of code for that :). Thanks for the up vote.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close :)

Try `^\s*meaning(?= +\S)`

Additional `(?= +\S)` at the end will ensure that what follows is spaces and some non-whitespace character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDowI9/2)

Comment: This won't work, because `.` also matches whitespace.  So, your pattern would match `meaning` followed by a singe space, which isn't right.

Comment: This still isn't right.  Now, you would reject an input like `meaning of life`, when in fact `meaning` _can_ be followed by whitespace, provided that some other non whitespace word does appear later on in the same line.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks again, sometimes I type faster than I think ;)